# MP3の音楽ファイルから、JASRACの作品コードを取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: api, mp3

お世話になります。

音楽のMP3ファイルのデータベース管理をしたいと思っているのですが、ファイル名や
曲名ではユニークなキーにはできないので、重複のないIDをとれればと思い、
JASRACに登録されている『XXX-XXXX-X』の八ケタの英数字でできている作品コードを
キーにしようと考えたのですが、それを取得できる方法がないかと探しています。

MP3のタグ情報の中にあるのであれば、解析して取得できるのですが、入っていない場合は
JASRACのWebページの検索機能にアーティスト名とタイトルを渡して…といったことを
プログラムでやりたいのですが、その方法などありましたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: MP3ならID3タグを利用できるでしょうが、さすがに「JASRACの作品コード」というフィールドは無いと思うので、代わりに「コメント」フィールドを利用する方法が考えられます。

Comment: MP3の音楽ファイルの入手元によってID3タグの有無が変わる気がします

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに、MP3タグは『なくても問題ない』ものですから、そこにデータを期待するのは無理かもしれません。『JASRAC』と言っていますが、とにかく重複しないキーであればいいと思うのですが、そうなるとやはりアーティスト名とタイトル名との組み合わせをキーとして使うとかないのでしょうか…。

Answer (score 2):

`mp3`はワールドワイドなフォーマットであるのに対し、`JASRAC`は日本の楽曲管理団体なので、`mp3`フォーマットに対し`JASRAC`のコードを埋め込むことは義務化されていません。

なので、`mp3`のタグから`JASRAC`コードを取得することは、`JASRAC`コードを埋め込まれた`mp3`からしかできません。

そこで、音響指紋を用いた音楽データーベスの`MusicBrainz`に音響指紋を渡し、作者・曲名を受けとり、`JASRAC`のデーターベースから、該当する組み合わせに対する`JASRAC`コードを受けとるのが現実的かなぁと思います。

[参考](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz)(MusicBrainzのWikipedia(jp)のページ)

MusicBrainzへアクセスする.Netライブラリーの一つに[この様なもの](https://github.com/Zastai/MusicBrainz)があるようです。
[GitHub](https://github.com/)でMusicBrainzをキーワードに検索すれば他にもありそうです。

*MusicBrainzのクライアントライブラリーは、「MusicBrainz Library C#」で検索して見つけました*

Comment: ありがとうございます。もっとも求めていた方法の気がします。こちらのMusicBrainzから音響指紋を渡して作者・曲名を受け取るまでを行うライブラリなどはありますでしょうか。できればC#等の.Netが希望なのですが。ここで何かユニークとなるキーが取得できれば、JASRACにこだわる必要もないのですが…。